# Spring не использует прокси

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

В чужом проекте столкнулся со странной работой спринга, которой не могу найти объяснения. Перестало выполняться сохранение в бд, пошёл посмотреть есть ли `@Transactional`. Он был, открываю в дебаге и вижу что у бина нет прокси. Делаю рестарт смотрю снова и прокся есть проваливаюсь в cglib как положено. В следующем рестарте нет. 
Раскопал и нашёл что в проекте в конфиге есть несколько бинов которые вручную регистрируются в `@PostConstuct` другого сервиса с помощью спрингового beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition() и пересоздавая эти бины спринг пересоздаёт (зачем то) зависимые от этих классов бины и по какой-то непонятной причине в них он не ходит через cglib. 
Пофиксить то я это пофиксил, но не понимаю  почему потерялась прокся ?